# What's the minimum version of OS X that supports File System Events?

Tags: macos, fsevents

I'd like to use FSEvents aka File System Events to listen to changes to the contents of a folder hierarchy. In my tests, File System Events does a superb job. However I can't find info as to whether it works on Tiger.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The header files usually know best

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20091026-g73ppybjtif46wtmjwptn4sxhi.png](http://img.skitch.com/20091026-g73ppybjtif46wtmjwptn4sxhi.png)